# Scaling font size to width of label iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

So, I recently starting learning Swift and was wondering how you would scale text within your labels depending on the screen size. I've seen a few questions similar to this, but they seem rather complicated. I'm trying to do it like this, but this doesn't seem to work.

> UIlabel1.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

I've connected the label to the code and set a few constraints. 
Equal width Constraint
Equal height Constraint
Center X Alignment Constraint
Vertical Space Constraint

The constraints are linked to the view controller so that the actual label size
scales with the screen size. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation for `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`:

> Normally, the label text is drawn with the font you specify in the **font** property. If this property is set to **true**, and the text in the **text** property exceeds the label’s bounding rectangle, the label reduces the font size until the string fits or the minimum font scale is reached. The default value for this property is **false**. If you change it to **true**, be sure that you also set an appropriate minimum font scale by modifying the **minimumScaleFactor** property.

This says that you must set `minimumScaleFactor` when using `adjustsFontSizeToWidth` in order for your font to be scaled.

But notice this scaling is one direction only. Your font size will get *smaller* if needed to display your text, but not *larger* than the font size you've set.

Given that, try setting the font size to the value appropriate for the largest screen on which your app will run. On smaller screens, it will scale down to fit, as far as the limit you specify for `minimumScaleFactor` will allow.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Autoshrink` in storyboard

[image]

Change it to `Minimum Font Scale` or `Minimum Font Size`

Comment: What is your `Minimum Font Size` value ? Can you set it smaller to test ?

Comment: I'm assuming what minimum font size does is that it makes sure that no matter how small the screen or label gets that's the smallest font size it could ever be. I set it to 30

Comment: Let set it to 8. It is the smallest font size that can scale.

Comment: Ok, and what do I put as font size for the label?

Comment: You can keep you current font size of the label. But set Minimum Font Size smaller so that it can scale to fit width.